# webservice ready model not attribute use @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring

Our problem consist in ready object with model, when ready attribute for attribute can ready.

- Project with spring 4.2.4-RELEASE
- User jackson 2.8.0

Describe =>

What we do, we do one webservice based in RestController of the Spring, we must receive HTTP requests
**POST** method, **content-type application / x-www-form-urlencoded** until now we ready object with by parameters this working **@RequestParam("event") String  event**, but the object has many parameters, the object call data has many properties. without it running we need to write a 5 line averaging code for method. if working @RequestBody there is one parameter, it's very fast.

```js
**webservice rest server**

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = /invoice)
public class Invoice
{
 //invoice create
 @RequestMapping(value = /{id}/create, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @Produces(value = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
 @Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
 public @ResponseBody String createInvoice(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
  @RequestBody Notification notificationData)
 {
  return "OK";
 }

 //change state invoice, first state
 @RequestMapping(value = /{id}/change, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @Produces(value = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
 @Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
 public String changeState(@PathVariable(value = id) String id, @RequestParam("event") String event, 
  @RequestParam ("data[id]") String dataId, @RequestParam("data[account_id]") String accout)
 {
  // call arrived here, with value of variable
  return "OK";
 }

 //change state invoice, second state
 @RequestMapping(value = /{id}/change, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @Produces(value = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
 @Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
 public String changeState(@PathVariable(value = id) String id, @RequestBody Notification notificationData)
 {
  // not arrived here
  return "OK";
 }
}

**model** 
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Notification implements Serializable
{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @JsonProperty("data")
 private Data   data;

 @JsonProperty("event")
 private String   event;
}

**child model**
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data implements Serializable
{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @JsonProperty("id")
 private String   id;

 @JsonProperty("account_id")
 private String   account;
}


**part of converter**


@Configuration(value = "webapp")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SysWebAppInitializer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
 implements WebApplicationInitializer{

 private static final Charset   UTF8    = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

 private static final List<MediaType> mediaType   =
 Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application", "json", UTF8), 
 new MediaType("text", "plain", UTF8), new MediaType("text", "html", UTF8),
 new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", UTF8), 
 new MediaType("application", "x-www-form-urlencoded",UTF8));
 
 
 @Bean(name = "jackson2Converter")
 @Scope("prototype")
 public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2Converter()
 {
  final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2Converter =
  new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
  jackson2Converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaType);
  jackson2Converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper().
  configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false));
  return jackson2Converter;
 }

 @Override
 public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
 {
  converters.addAll(this.buildListConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()));
 }
}

**same stacktrace wrong, same call method create**

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'event': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@4efc31a9; line: 1, column: 7]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'event': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@4efc31a9; line: 1, column: 7]
```

We need ready a model object, not attribute

Comment: There is a lot more information needed here. What does the Json document that you attempted to POST look like? What does the method signature for this Controller method look like, and finally, what POJO were you attempting to bind this data to?

Comment: sory i'm edit and send before finish

Comment: Still need the request body that is failing. Is it a JSON doc or form data? Also, you didn't post the `Data` class that is referenced in `Notification`

Comment: ya, post in code, call Data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: i'm try same  write details and change the title for can get more help of the community

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the exception says that there is something wrong with your json. You need to find what JSON is actually being parsed. Run the application within a debugger, set a breakpoint on the relevant constructor for JsonParseException ... then find out what is in the ByteArrayInputStream that it is attempting to parse.

Comment: ya, same erro a parse, but i'm don't know solved this, we make many configurations, when not parameters in method call arrived, if put parameter @requestBody, sametimes generete erros other not.